# Amavisd on OpenSUSE Leap 15.5 - use with exim - Can't connect to TCP port 10024 on 127.0.0.1 [Permission denied]

Tags: exim, opensuse, amavis

Like many amateur sysadmins, I'm taking advantage of the festive period to upgrade my mail server.  Having battled with the vagaries of the HP Gen8 microserver to get Leap 15.5 up and running, all that seems to be in my way of changing out the newly-built machine for the old one is my inability to get amavis running in the same set-up configuration: frustratingly, it won't.

Starting it causes it to die gracefully with the error message **"Can't connect to TCP port 10024 on 127.0.0.1 [Permission denied]"** but nothing else uses this port and it's only supposed to LISTEN on this port in the same way that the current mail server does happily. A check with netstat confirms nothing else is using port 10024 and the only "non-standard" feature of the new build is that IPv6 is not in use - I've confirmed that Perl module Net::Server *(which generates the error)* is correctly trying to make an IPv4 connection when it fails.

I might be missing the obvious but I've run out of ideas and 2024 is looming... :)